# dynamically add property with type to existing type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an API call that return set parameters and then one property that is specific for that endpoint, This is what I am currently returning:

```
interface QueryResponseData {
  QueryResponse: {
    startPosition: number;
    totalCount: number;
    maxResults: number;
    [module: string]: any;
  };
  time: string;
}
```

I would like to make it more specific like

```
interface QueryResponseData {
  QueryResponse: {
    startPosition: number;
    totalCount: number;
    maxResults: number;
    Invoice: IInvoice;
  };
  time: string;
}
```

What I dont know know is how to call this to add the module name and type properly.  Not sure if I can use the entityName since that is the same name as the module that is being returned?

Where I am at the moment

```
// NOT WORRKING
interface QueryResponse {
  startPosition: number;
  totalCount: number;
  maxResults: number;
}

// T = IInvoice
const test = <T>(entityName: string) => {
  return Axios.get<{
// Gives Error: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type
    QueryResponse: QueryResponse & {[entityName]: T}
    time: string
  }>(url);
}
```

Comment: Does this solution answer your question? https://tsplay.dev/mLry4w If so I will post an answer an explain it, if you like.

Comment: Is ther no way to do something like this?
const test = <K,T>(entityName: K, url: string) => {
  return Axios.get<{
    QueryResponse: QueryResponse<K, T>
    time: string
  }>(url); and have the argument be the type?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting this to work by creating a interface with all the types I want.

- QuickbooksTypes is the interface with all the main types in it.
- QueryRequest is just a holder of the other core fields sent over.
- The Array<> is because the response is an array of the items.
- The P part is to clean up the return so it does not have the & in the return

```js
export interface QuickbooksTypes {
  // ...
  Exchangerate: Exchangerate;
  Invoice: Invoice;
  Item: Item;
  // ...
}

interface QueryRequest {
  startPosition: number;
  totalCount: number;
  maxResults: number;
}

query = async <K extends keyof QuickbooksTypes>(
    entityName: K,
    queryInput?: QueryInput | null
  ): {
      QueryResponse: {
        [P in keyof (QueryRequest &
          Record<K, Array<QuickbooksTypes[K]>>)]?: (QueryRequest &
          Record<K, Array<QuickbooksTypes[K]>>)[P];
      };
      time: string;
    } => {
        ...
    }
```

This gives a return like this

```
(property) Quickbooks.findInvoices: (criteria?: QueryInput) => Promise<{
    QueryResponse: {
        startPosition?: number;
        totalCount?: number;
        maxResults?: number;
        Invoice?: Invoice[];
    };
    time: string;
}>
```